# Finding the inverse of the differential $d\pi_{i_p} : T_p( M_1 \times \dots \times M_k) \to T_{p_i}M_i$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential, tangent-spaces

> Suppose that $M_1, \dots, M_k$ are smooth manifolds. Show that for each $i$ the projection $\pi_i : M_1 \times \dots \times M_k \to M_i$ is a smooth submersion.

I've shown the smoothness of the projection map earlier so to prove this I need to show surjectivity of the differential $d\pi_{i_p}$ at $p=(p_1, \dots, p_k) \in M_1 \times \dots \times M_k$.

My friend suggested me to define a map $i_{M_i}:M_i \to M_1 \times \dots \times M_k$ as $i_{M_i}(x)=(x^1, \dots x, \dots,x^k)$ where each except the i'th position is fixed.

With this map I think I can do the proof as follows. $$(d\pi_{i_p} \circ di_{M_{i_{p_i}}})(v)f = d(\pi_i \circ i_{M_i})_{p_i}(v)f = v(f \circ \pi_i \circ i_{M_i})= v(f)$$ which implies that $di_{M_i}:T_{p_i}M_i \to T_p (M_1, \dots, M_k)$ is an inverse for $d\pi_{i_p}$ and so $d\pi_{i_p}$ must be surjective.

What is confusing to me is this map $i_{M_i}$. What is the purpose of it and why even consider it? It's like the inverse of the projection map or something? I don't think I could have done this without it.

Comment: No, it's not the inverse (and by an obvious dimension count, it is not invertible). For inverse functions, the composition in the other order must also yield the identity. Anyway, based on what you wrote, this equality is useful because if a composition equals identity, then in particular the composition is surjective, so the "outer" function must be surjective.

Comment: So in a sense it's only good for this particular case? I feel like it's coming from thin air and there is no natural way to think about it. If I look at this map defined on say $\Bbb R^2$, then it appears that I can use it to "shift" either the $x$-axis or $y$-axis.

Comment: I think that this kind of maps (submersions) and "right inverses" appears constantly in the theory of bundles, sheaves, fibrations, coverings, and such.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a "right" inverse of $\pi_i$, because $\pi_i\circ i_{M_i}$ is equal to the identity map $Id_{M_i}$ of $M_i$. Knowing that, and applying the chain rule, one gets the same result that you obtained:

$$Id_{T_{p_i}M_i} = d_{p_i}(Id_{M_i}) = d_{p_i}(\pi_i\circ i_{M_i}) = d_p\pi_i \circ d_{p_i}i_{M_i}$$

Which readily shows that $d_p\pi_i$ has a right inverse.

In differential geometry (and other fields), a right inverse of $\pi_i$ is called a "section" of the map $\pi_i$.

A submersion $\pi: M \rightarrow N$ is a map which "projects" the manifold $M$ onto $N$ in such a way that the fiber of each point $q\in N$ is a submanifold of $M$ (kinda like a division of $N$ into "leaves", or a "foliation", though that has its own meaning).

A differentiable section consists on "choosing" for each $q\in N$, a point $s(q)\in M$ in the fiber of $q$ ("above" $q$),  that is, such that $\pi(s(q)) = q$. If the section is differentiable, it looks like you are "embedding" $N$ into a "leave" of $M$ or a "cut" of $M$ (that's why it's called a "section", it's like a slice of ham if for example $N$ is a surface).

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is right, although I guess you don’t appreciate the technique.

If $f$ and $g$ are functions such that $f \circ g$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective. It is asked to show that $f=d\pi_{i_p}$ is surjective and your calculations show that $g= di_{M_{i_{p_i}}}$ is a required map.